# Multiprocessing only running first line of code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Hi Im facing issues with trying to get multiprocesssing to work. So after the `apply_async` call, it only executes the first line of the function and nothing else. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```py
tp = ThreadPool(processes=4)

for file in listdir(alignDir):
    tp.apply_async(trim, (file,))
    sleep(0.5)

tp.close()
tp.join()
```

```
def trim(file):
    print("Trimming " + file)
    input_file = alignDir + file    
    print(input_file)
```

Im getting the following results

```
Start Trimming.
Trimming Africa_HA_merged_aligned.fasta
Trimming Africa_MP_merged_aligned.fasta
Trimming Africa_NA_merged_aligned.fasta
Trimming Africa_NP_merged_aligned.fasta
Trimming Africa_NS_merged_aligned.fasta
Trimming Africa_PA_merged_aligned.fasta
.
.
.
all the way to the end and nothing was actually done
```

instead of

```
Start Trimming.
Trimming Africa_HA_merged_aligned.fasta
someinputfile string
Trimming Africa_MP_merged_aligned.fasta
anotherinputfile string
Trimming Africa_NA_merged_aligned.fasta
anotherinputfile string
.
.
.
and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's likely happening is that `trim` is throwing an exception, but there's nowhere for that exception to go, so it gets dropped. The script is asking for a number of things to be done in the background using `apply_async`, but it never asks for the results (using i.e. `get`), so those results - including possible exceptions - never make it anywhere.

One way to fix this would be to replace this loop:

```
for file in listdir(alignDir):
    tp.apply_async(trim, (file,))
```

with something like the `map` method, which "...chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks..." and, crucially, "blocks until the result is ready" ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html)), something like:

```
tp.map(trim, listdir(alignDir))
```

The size of these chunks is configurable; your existing loop would be equivalent to a chunk size of 1.

Because the script now waits for results, it notices if instead of results there's an exception, and that exception is propagated and logged as usual.

Comment: Wow you are absolutely right! There was a typo that i missed in the string that alignDir was pointing to that threw an exception. I have been trying to resolve this for hours and this was it. Thank you!